# Multiple servlet communication

Tags: java, servlets, web, tomcat8

I have a simple servlet 'Login' deployed in Server A tomcat

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>

<form method="post" action="Validate">
 User: <input type="text" name="user" /><br/>
Password: <input type="text" name="pass" ><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

**Validate.java**

```
   doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String name = request.getParameter("user");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

    if(pass.equals("1234"))
    {
        //creating a session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user", name);
        response.sendRedirect("Welcome");

    }
    else
    {
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         out.println("Wrong password!!!");
    }
}
```

**Welcome.Java**

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String user = (String)session.getAttribute("user");
    out.println("Welcome"+user);
}
```

This set up works fine.

Now what I want to try is to create another Servlet 'Validate' which would be deployed in another Server B tomcat with a different IP. I need to pass the parameters from Servlet 'Login' to Servlet 'Validate' which will then validate the credentials and send back the validation message, a String, to the Servlet 'Login' which will then display the same on its index.jsp page.

Please provide some help on this. Let me also add that I have no prior experience in servlets.

Comment: You can always send a HTTP(S) request to server B from A, with the values as headers, or URL encoded parameters in the body

Comment: Thanks, but could you please show some example/ code. As I said, I have not had any experience with this.